# Check for specific words that is not exist in document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to search through my document to count the number of documents that contains specific word and other that does not have that specific word in kibana4.

can anyone help me about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data table visualization
Use the filter agg type.
And give "NOT fieldName:missingValue" , to show the missing documents. 
and "fieldName:value" , to show documents having the word.